# Why does a process appear as 'not responding' with tasklist, but 'running' in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, taskmanager

Between running `tasklist -fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"` and looking up the process in Task Manager, why would `tasklist` indicate `NOT RESPONDING` while Task Manager says otherwise, or vice versa?

They both had the same `pid` yet different apparent statuses?

'tasklist' output vs Task Manager processes

[image: 'tasklist' output vs Task Manager processes]

The same applies for the node.exe which aren't on screen.

Comment: In Task Manager's Details page, the values for the `Status` column are "Running" or "Suspended". It doesn't check for responsiveness.

Comment: @RaymondChen. I don't believe that is correct. [Task manager with `Not Responding` status](https://i.imgur.com/y0mJZvA.png).

I created a WPF application and put the UI thread to sleep for 10000ms and Task Manager will show the executable as not responding.
And `tasklist` will show the same status.

Comment: Hm, interesting, because I made one of my own apps stop responding and Task Manager didn't care. The concept of "responding" or not is a UI concept, not a process concept, so this column is basically heuristics.